# Responsive design, absolute position a .png img to always be bottom left AND inside the left column

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-position, responsive-images

So I want an image to always be in the left column at the bottom of the screen. I can't seem to keep the image in that column when resizing. The image itself is not responsive, but I would like it to be, so as to stay in the left col.
The image being placed in is larger than the left column, hence the image width being 100% Is this not correct?

Thank you for your time, if you have any to spare.

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header">
    </div><!--header-->

    <div id="col1">
        <div class="mascot">
            <img id="gas_mask_lancer" src="images/german_cavalry.png" alt="German Lancer from the great war. Equiped with a gas mask, lance, rifle and horse">
        </div><!--mascot-->
    </div><!--col1-->

    <div id="col2">

        <div id="content">
        </div><!--content-->

        <div id="footer">
        </div><!--footer-->

    </div><!--col2-->
    <div class="clear_both"></div>

</div><!--wrapper-->
```

```css
#wrapper {
    margin:auto;
    width:100%;
}

#col1 {
    min-height:900px;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    max-width:169px;
    width:16.5686%;
    background-color:#6b7069;
}

#gas_mask_lancer{
    width:100%;
    max-width:167px;
    margin:auto;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:1%;
}

#col2 {
    min-height:900px;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    width:83.4313%;
    background-color:#c3b091;
}

#header {
    background-color:#6b7069;
    min-height:240px;
}

#content {
    min-height:700px;
}

#footer {
    background-color:#000;
    min-height:257px;
}

.clear_both {
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: your question is---- it's hard to understand, can u input some images to picturing us what do u want to do.

Comment: As continue of what @Obink wrote, what you want to achieve ? you want the image to be on left of the black background column? or you want the image to stay left-bottom of the screen? 
https://jsfiddle.net/q4pzy2n7/

Comment: @Oshrib the first thing to make it clear, this question ===an image to always be in the left column at the bottom of the screen.=== so why don't you put your image position fixed, then set left:0 bottom:0?

Comment: the image that is supposed to be in the left column should occupy 169px out of 1020px and the black footer should bee right of that coumn.